# Ethernet causes my PC to crash

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot, 22.04, realtek

I have a PC with a dual boot Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS / Windows 11 on two separate hard drives that has been running for several months. At the moment, Windows is working perfectly well, but when I boot into Ubuntu, I get this error message:

```
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean, 354068/30531584 files, 8369977/122096128 blocks
[10.986316]
[14.448748] r8169 000:05:00.0 enp5s0: rtl_ocp_gphy_cond == 1 (loop: 10, delay:25)
[16.869813] r8169 000:05:00.0 enp5s0: rtl_ocp_gphy_cond == 1 (loop: 10, delay:25)
```

Then the login screen comes up and I'm having trouble typing my password (there's a lot of latency when I press a key) and my keyboard is QWERTY (which it shouldn't be).
The PC reboots when I'm on this login screen, so I can't access Ubuntu.

My ethernet connection works fine on Windows.

Comment: See if you can boot into Recovery Mode from the GRuB menu and try to install the `r8168-dkms` driver.  Although the `r8168` driver should blacklist the old driver, try blacklisting the r8169 driver as well before rebooting.  `echo "blacklist r8169" | tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems to be working better now. Even though I've got an ethernet connection back, I get another error message on boot: ```[0.697192] amd_gpio AMDI0030:00: Invalid config param 0014```. Do you think this error is linked to the same problem?

Comment: Looks like that is a different issue.  From looking around the internets I am seeing that it has to do with the video card and the Kernel.  Some are saying the Kernel needs to be patched or wait till a newer kernel comes out.  Even looking at one like https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/amd-linux-graphics-drivers-and-how-they-are-used-in-slackware-4175692575/page7.html it appears that it may just be a warning and not actually causing any issues.

Comment: Ethernet worked fine on Ubuntu, even after several reboots, until I booted on Windows. Now a new error message appears when I try to boot to Ubuntu: ```r9168 000:04:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Invalid ether addr ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff````. Then the PC crashes and restarts.

Comment: Check with your motherboard manufacturer.  Sounds like it may have flashed a firmware to the board erasing the MAC address that was assigned to the onboard NIC.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that